# How to add custom format for selected cell in react-data-grid?

Tags: react-data-grid

Documentation addresses only the event handling https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/#/examples/cell-selection-events.

**Are there any CSS classes that are assigned to the selected cell?** Currently the selected cell has pale blue border but I would like to change this. Such change of style is not possible with `ReactDataGrid.onCellSelected`, because the `formatter.render()` event is fired first and only then `onCellSelected` event is fired. Yes, I can read the coordinates of the selected cell in `onCellSelected`, but I can not use those coordinates for formatting, because `formatter.render()` is executed before `onCellSelected`, i.e., coordintates of new newly selected cell are not available in the time moment when they should be read.

I do not consider this as bug, of course, there should be another mechanism how one can format the selected cell, but at present I can not find this mechanism in documentation. I went through the generated code in web console and I did not managed to find any additional class name that could have been added to the selected cell by the grid.

**So, what is the right mechanism how to format the selected cell?**

Maybe I can call (somehow) `formatter.render()` of the selected cell inside `onCellSelected` somehow? And that would solve my issue?